# Is $\sup\{t>0:F(t)>0 \in [0,t]\}$ an incorrect math expression?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, notation

I saw the following in a journal paper and the notation looks wrong - am I right?

$$t_1 = \sup\{t>0:F(t)>0 \in [0,t]\}$$

I would like to translate this into an English sentence, but I don't understand how $F(t)>0$ can mean $F(t) \in [0,t]$?!

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: @Taro Does $F(t)>0\in[0,t]$ mean that $F(t)>0$ and that $F(t)\in[0,t]$?

Comment: Wow. I would *guess* that the author meant $\{t>0: F(s)>0 \text{ for all } s\in [0,t]\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two problems.  The first is the last $t$ should probably be a different variable, say $x$.  Then the best I can do, and I don't think it says this correctly, is that the range of $t$ for which $F(t) \gt 0$, sometimes called the support of $F$, is a subset (not element) of $[0,x]$.  $t_1$ is then the sup of all the $t$'s which have support in $[0,x]$

Comment: Should $x$ be positive as well?

Comment: Yes, it would have to be.  Otherwise you don't have $[0,x]$ an interval.  It would make sense to ask that $F(t) \gt 0 \subset [x,0]$ with $x \lt 0$